# access one guest os from another guest os in virtualbox through Python

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, python

**Some background** 
So I am trying to work on a certain open source project. The open source software in question is designed to work on a VMWare workstation and I am trying to contribute to the project to try to make it work on VirtualBox as well.

The project in question is a Python project. The architecture, as discussed in the documentation of the project, is such:

The base OS is 64 bit Ubuntu (let's call it UBUNTU1) 
The Virtualization software is VMware Workstation running on the host. The guest OS is another 64 bit Ubuntu. (let's call it UBUNTU2)

Now at a certain place in the project, the project starts the guest OS programmatically through a Python subprocess() call. So it simply passes the path to the vmrun utility, the path to the .vmx file (of the guest OS) and a few additional control arguments to the subprocess call and starts up the guest OS.

The tool has a lot of other dependencies as well, that are available for Ubuntu alone and not for Mac, or at least are really difficult to set up on Mac OSX El capitan (not talking of Windows for now)

So now, my thought process is that I will need to make it run on Ubuntu itself somehow. So below is what I have been trying to do:

**1st approach:** 
Architecture is such:
Base OS - Mac OSX 64 bit
Virtualization software - VirtualBox
Guest OS - Ubuntu 64 bit (UBUNTU1 from the reference above). Inside this guest OS, install virtual box again and install the guest Ubuntu 64 bit (UBUNTU2)

But some research showed that although it might work, VirtualBox does not SUPPORT nested VMs.

**So now the next approach:**
Architecture is such:
Base OS - Mac OSX 64 bit
Virtualization software - VirtualBox
Guest OS - Ubuntu 64 bit (UBUNTU1 from the reference above)
A second guest OS - also Ubuntu 64 bit (UBUNTU2 from the reference above)

Now when the python project is run on UBUNTU1, and at the point when it must start UBUNTU2 programmatically,

1. can it be done, starting one guest OS from another guest OS?
   vboxmanage start can be used, but it's a tool available to the host
   machine (Mac) and not to UBUNTU1. Even if I install vboxmanage on
   UBUNTU1, and share the .vbox image of UBUNTU2 through shared folder
   from Mac to UBUNTU1, and also register it, I can not start UBUNTU2
   from inside UBUNTU1.
2. Diving a bit to the internals for a better understanding, is it not that UBUNTU1 and UBUNTU2 (the 2 guest OS in Mac) when running, are just 2 processes like any other? And if yes, then can't I just try to do some inter process communication between the 2 guests and give the needed process context of UBUNTU2 to UBUNTU1 ?

Please bare with my novice questions around processes. I am trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to set up a fresh Ubuntu on a 2nd Partition or on a External HardDrive for UBUNTU1 than using vm software inside of vm software - if you have both ubuntu's as a guest on mac os the you can't directly startup ubuntu2 from ubuntu1 (just like you can't power on a pc from another - yes there is power on lan which can do this on real pc's but on vm's there is no power on lan)  then you need to send your commands from ubuntu1 to your mac to fire up ubuntu2 you could try to use ssh & xargs to connect from your ubuntu1 to the mac if they are in the same network

Comment: setting up a second partition or an external HD is something I would try to avoid, as all users might not really be comfortable doing so. And the whole idea is to get it across to more number of users by allowing it to work with VirtualBox rather than VMWare workstation alone.